# Attribute table: Add columns from one layer to the other one (both shp types)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have two layers, both shp type. One contains villages with all their details, the other one is a result from a point sampling tool, so two columns - population density and elevation.

What I would like to do is to add the two columns to the attribute table of villages layer.

I went to the attribute table of villages layer and tried to add these two columns but without result.

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: Is villages a polygon layer or another point layer?

Comment: villages are points

Comment: probably solvable with spatial join, but you should provide more info

Comment: @radouxju what kind of info? Both layers are shp types files. Both are points on a map. Same amount of columns (as one layer describe the other one)

Comment: Do both layers share a common field or attribute?

Comment: if you have a common code to link the two table, then you can join attribute tables. If you only have the spatial location, the you can use spatial join. The answer depends on what you have.

Comment: @Joseph No they don't. First layer has these columns: osm_id, place, name, capital, type, z_order, ORIG_FID. The second one has these columns: elevation, population. Both have the same amount of lignes (obviously).

Comment: @radouxju Perfect ! The spatial join : Vector -> Data mng tools -> Join attributes by location works. Thank you a lot